# How does the negative (not) conditional work in Twig?

Tags: templating, conditional

If I write:

```
{% if entry.section not 'Homepage' %}Blabla {% endif %}
```

this results in the error:

> Unexpected token "operator" of value "not" ("end of statement block"
>   expected)

But if I write:

```
{% if entry.section != 'Homepage' %}Blabla {% endif %}
```

It works.

In the [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html) docs there is no mentioning of `!=` as an operator but it seems to be working just fine. Is `!=` a craft specific operator?

So whats the difference between `not` and `!=` ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe 'not' is only used for checking values that are 'false'. != (and ==, etc) are for string comparisons.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Twig `!=` is a [comparison](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons) operator.

> The following comparison operators are supported in any expression: ==, !=, <, >, >=, and <=

You can use `!=` to compare any two things that php lets you compare, and what you get back is a boolean.

Twig `not` is a [logic](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math) operator. (so are `and` and `or`)

> not: Negates a statement.

Answer (score 6):

You could write `{% if not entry.section == 'Homepage' %}`

Use `not` to perform a negative test, not a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for:

```twig
{% if entry.section not same as('Homepage') %}Blabla {% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that this will compare the translated `name` of the section, not the unique `handle` attribute since the `__toString` function doesn't return the `handle`. Of course it is possible but I would not suggest to do this. The better approach would be to check the handle. When you create a new locale your condition might fail due to different translations for `Homepage`

Answer (score 1):

For comparing strings and negating the result I'm using the following construction:

```twig
{% set is_training = course_type == 'training' %}
...
{% if not is_training %}
...
```